# I want to only remove grouped commas from this csv to change the number of variables to two

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv, text-formatting, csv-simple

I have a csv where the first few rows look like this

```
c("4288", "57534"),MIB1
c("2272", "2385"),FHIT
c("5550", "10531", "56239"),PREP
c("25809", "23669"),TTLL1
```

I want to manipulate the number of variables so that everything grouped in parenthesis is one variable. Unfortunately my document has several entries like line 3 where there are more than one comma separating the values inside parenthesis.

Is there a sed expression capable of manipulating only the commas inside the parenthesis?

The expected output would be something like this:

```
c("4288" "57534"), MIB1
c("2272" "2385"),FHIT
c("5550" "10531" "56239"),PREP
c("25809" "23669"),TTLL1
```

Cheers.

Comment: For this to be an actual CSV file, the fields containing commas would be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution I have answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580769/72456), that will also apply to your question with a bit modification here:

```
sed -E ':loop s/(\([^)]*),([^)]*\))/\1\2/; t loop' infile
```

#### Breaking down:

**Note**: un-escaped `(` or `)` outside character class `[...]` is to used for grouping match; escaped `\(` or `\)` or within character class `[...]` will match literal `(` and `)`; `^` is negation match, so `[^)]` matches "*any single character but not a `)`*".

then we have:

`(\([^)]*)`: first group match, back referend `\1` is referring to.
`,`: match a single comma.
`([^)]*\))`: second group match, back-reference `\2` is referring  to.

Considering one sample line like below and explaining on how this match works:

```
c(("4288", "57534", "somtoher")),d("f1", "f2", "f3"),MIB1
```

this `(\([^)]*),([^)]*\))` will match:

1. from very first open parenthesis `(` followed by anything but not a `)` and up-to last `,` to the first close parenthesis `)`; so, first group match `\1` will match `(("4288", "57534",` part of the sample line at above;
2. then anything after last `,` to the first close parenthesis up-to first close parenthesis and `)` itself will be in second group match `\2`; it will be  `"somtoher")` part of the sample line above.
3. in replacement part in `\1\2`, we revert the both matched groups back but dropped comma between them.
4. `:loop s///; t loop`; do steps 1 to 3 in until all commas between `(`&`)` cleared in a sed's loop (`loop` is used as label).

   at first attempt, our sample line would change to:

   ```
   c(("4288", "57534" "somtoher")),d("f1", "f2", "f3"),MIB1
   ```

   at second attempt would be:

   ```
   c(("4288" "57534" "somtoher")),d("f1", "f2", "f3"),MIB1
   ```

   at third attempt would be:

   ```
   c(("4288" "57534" "somtoher")),d("f1", "f2" "f3"),MIB1
   ```

   and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` instead of `sed` to get more advanced regular expressions:

```
perl -pe 's/(?:\G[^,)]*|\([^,)]*)\K,(?=.*?\))//g' input.csv
c("4288" "57534"),MIB1
c("2272" "2385"),FHIT
c("5550" "10531" "56239"),PREP
c("25809" "23669"),TTLL1
```

This will remove all commas that appear inside parenthesis.